# How to apply javascript code once component rendering done in angularjs 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have component, created in angularjs 1.5. I want to add some logic in javascript once my whole component DOM is ready.

I have tried lifecycle function of component $postLink. But it is not working.

```
function ModelTableController($scope, $rootScop) {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.data = null;
        $ctrl.MetricLibraryCode = 'QUENTANT';
        $ctrl.rowSelected = null;


        $ctrl.$postLink = function () {
            console.log('postlink');
            var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
            for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
                tr[i].style.backgroundColor = i % 2 ? '#2C3135' : '#262a2e';
            }
        };        
    }
})();
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

thanks

Comment: How come you have such a use case in angular???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$timeout`, this will add it's callback to scheduler and will be executed after document is ready.

```
$timeout(function(){
  // do things here.
})
```